# setRowspan in iText not working

Tags: java, itext, html-table

I'm using iText 5.4.4 to generate pdf. I have created a table and the first row (which is a heading) has a column span of 4 columns. After that I tried using `cell.setRowspan(2)` to make the heading span 2 rows but that doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my code snippet:

```
PdfPCell cell;
cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Parent Details",font));
cell.setColspan(4);
cell.setRowspan(2);
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Phrase.ALIGN_CENTER);
cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
table.addCell(cell);
```

In `iText in Action` book the author says - "There is no method setRowspan() in PdfPTable/PdfPCell." How come NetBeans is not throwing error if such a method does not exists? Also, how do I make my heading span 2 rows? Is there any workaround other than using a nested table?

Comment: *In iText in Action book the author says - "There is no method setRowspan() in PdfPTable/PdfPCell." How come NetBeans is not throwing error if such a method does not exists?* - I assume you have the first edition of that book. `setRowspan` was introduced 7 years after `setColspan`; maybe the book was written in the time between?

Comment: I think so. But why is `setRowspan` not working?

Comment: Well, it is, cf. my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you did not provide enough code to reproduce the issue. Thus, I can only give a sample to show that row span works all right:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("span-in-table.pdf"));
document.open();

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);

table.addCell("A");
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("B"));
cell.setColspan(2);
cell.setRowspan(2);
table.addCell(cell);
table.addCell("C");
table.addCell("D");
table.addCell("E");
table.addCell("F");

document.add(table);
document.close();
```

This sample produces this table:

[image: Result table with column span and row span on the right side]

Which looks pretty much as expected.

Or if you prefer the 2x2 cell on left side:

```
...
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("A"));
cell.setColspan(2);
cell.setRowspan(2);
table.addCell(cell);
table.addCell("B");
table.addCell("C");
table.addCell("D");
table.addCell("E");
table.addCell("F");

document.add(table);
...
```

resulting in

[image: Result table with column span and row span on the left side]

> In iText in Action book the author says - "There is no method setRowspan() in PdfPTable/PdfPCell." How come NetBeans is not throwing error if such a method does not exists?

Well, that was the first edition of iText in Action. In the second edition you can read:

> *There **was** a time when rowspan wasn't supported for `PdfPCells`. The only way to work around this **was** to use nested tables.*
>
> *(page 109 in [iText in Action — Second Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/))*

You can find the examples from chapter 4 *Organizing content in tables* [here](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=4).

Comment: What would you do if you wanted cell"A" to span two rows and two columns?

Comment: You mean both A and B being 2x2? Or just A?

Comment: I added an example with **A** instead of **B** spanning 2x2 cells.